# Why can't you make the selection of at least one tag required in a profile?

Tags: profile, tags

It is possible via the profile user interface to mark the tags field as required.

But, when the profile is displayed in user-create mode, the little red asterisk is absent and you can in fact add a record without entering a tag.

I've traced the problem to [this function call](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/48335576c076f2e321d622b2a81a217c64d1e229/CRM/Contact/Form/Edit/TagsAndGroups.php#L49), which allows you to make the group field required (provided it's displayed as check boxes). But there doesn't appear to be any code that would apply to tags.

This doesn't look like a programming error. So, I'm not sure if it simply was left out or if there is any underlying reason why you would not be able to do this?

Comment: Concur this problem existed (just tested on a dmaster d9 site) but have no explanation, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Peter for the feedback, I'm coming to the conclusion that the inability to require a tag is simply an overlooked feature. I will try to put together a PR in the coming days to address it.

Comment: I've submitted a fix upstream: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23645